Is it possible to render dynamic HTML content independently through AD B2C Custom Policy?
After Sign in, I want to render HTML content. This HTML content is dynamic and is returned from an endpoint. I want to render this HTML content in AD B2C custom Policy. So every time a user signs-in, in the sign-in flow it should render the dynamic HTML content while executing the same policy after clicking on sign in button on b2c login page. Is it possible to render dynamic HTML content through AD B2C Custom Policy?
I tried below the technical profile to call the RestApi(/htmlContent) which returns the HTML content and i am not able to call it.
  <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-GetHtmlContent">
          <DisplayName>Get HTML Content</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://example.com/data/htmlContent</Item>
            <!-- <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://returnhtml.azurewebsites.net/api/ReturnHtmlFunction</Item> -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">QueryString</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims /> 
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="htmlContent" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>


Below is the error i am getting
AADB2C: The request URI 'https://example.com/data/htmlContent' resolves to an IP address which is in a restricted IP range
Correlation ID: b2368d35-2f4f-48c2-8f33-4fdf8eeb60ed
Timestamp: 2024-08-09 19:11:04Z

Could you please share more details and edit the question?
